# hover and focus pseudo-classes action

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with `css` and I'm trying to add a dynamic pseudo-class in my selector. Here is the `HTML`-markup snippet.

```
<div id="child">
    <input type="text" id="text"/>
</div>
```

and it's corresponding `css`-style

```
input[type="text"]{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
}
input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus{
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#child{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 20px solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here is the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z78BN/5/) example. So when the mouse hovers over the `text` element the size of the text element is reduced as follows:

[image]

[image]

Would anyone know why this reduction in size is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in your code what is happening is that you have set the **input** fields width and height to 150px and 25px respectively.Now when you add **1px border** to it it will reduce the inside(white) portion of the input field to maintain the width and height as mentioned(150px and 25px). To solve this you can add 2px to both width and height on hover.Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/z78BN/6

```
input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus{
   width: 152px;
   height: 27px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of two things outline and pseudo 3d default border of input. 
Add

```
input[type="text"]{
    border: 1px solid aqua;
}

input[type="text"]:focus{
   outline:none;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work in FF or chrome. The appearance of a "reduction" in size still occurred.

Comment: @Phlume I dont see what you are saying in chrome. Change border width to say 5px and you'll see it is in fact expanded not reduced.

Comment: OP didn't want a 5px border though... Look at the example in the fiddle below. Pay particular attention to the lower right corner of the text box. Notice how it is nearly in the same location. Now remove the height/width properties and run it again... now see how the box's size appears to be "reduced".  Albeit the change is miniscule, but the appearance of a size shift occurs. Unfortunately with the `outline:none;` you suggested to fix the issue, the change still appeared and did not fix the problem like the fiddle below did.

Comment: @Phlume Typo in my edit messed up the answer. The real reason is pseudo 3d border so setting up bg color to it will eliminate this effect.